# How to display record to a datagridview to another datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two forms. When i click the selected record in the `datagridview` of form 1, i want to see the student history in form 2 by its `datagridview`.

**Expected Result**

[image]

**Database Relationship**
[image]

Code of passing the values from `datagridview` to `textbox`.

```
form2.txtStudLN.Text = dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value
form2.txtStudFN.Text = dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
form2.txtStudMN.Text = dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value.ToString()
```

The code of Form1_load

```
 cn.Open()

        Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.uspSELECTALL", cn)
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            dt.Clear()
            da.Fill(dt)
            dgv1.RowTemplate.Height = 50
            dgv1.DataSource = dt

        End Using
        cn.Close()
```

Comment: Dont you want *all* the rows in History related to a student clicked in form1?

Comment: @Plutonix . Not all. I only want SchoolYear, Levels, section ,DateEnrolled to display in the `datagridview` of form 2

Comment: but you want all **rows** related to a given student to show, no?

Comment: @Plutonix. No, I dont want

Comment: [Updated image](http://img2.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/21901/219010125627e431792fc34e5df5b79a260d4d03.jpg) I edit the image to understand clearly.

Comment: And what's the problem? Load data in form2 using :`SELECT * FROM StudentHistory WHERE StudentID=@StudentID` and show data in `DataGridView` of `Form2`